# trouble using JSON.stringify()

Tags: json, typescript, class, object

I am trying to paint an object attributes using console.log(JSON.stringify(object)) in TS and then converting it to JS.
However when i call the function it does not paint anything.
I create the object with the parameters of the class.
Here is the code:

```
*class app{
    constructor ( file: string ){}
}
function createApp(){
    let v = new app ( 'image 2');
    console.log(JSON.stringify ( v ) );
}
createApp();*
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Your object doesn't have any property. What do you expect JSON.stringify() to do with such an empty object? What's the point of providing an argument to the constructor if the constructor doesn't do anything with it?

Comment: Thank you, now i realized i must add a property and then put it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will output `{"file":"image 2"}`:

```
class app {
    constructor(private file: string) {}
}
function createApp(){
    let v = new app ( 'image 2');
    console.log(JSON.stringify ( v ) );
}
createApp();
```

But if you need object serialisation I would recommend next (because it more obvious that an example above):

```
class App {
    constructor(private file: string) {}

    public serialise() {
         return JSON.stringify({ file: this.file });
    }
}

function createApp(){
    let v = new app ( 'image 2');
    console.log(v.serialise());
}

createApp();
```